# AWS Textract - Is there a way to distinguish which words are in bold?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I'm using AWS's textract for documents, but it doesn't seem to have any detection for if the text is in bold. Is there something I'm missing or is that just not a feature?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bold text detection does not appear to be a current feature in Textract.

The Textract API returns [lines and words of text](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/how-it-works-lines-words.html) in a Block object.

The Block object data type is documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Block.html and does not have any properties related to the font weight (such as bold).

Comment: any ML models that do something similar?

Comment: @davids. Tesseract 3 has this feature. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/3.01/api/resultiterator.h#L95